# ¿Por qué no puedo crear un proyecto en Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular, web, angular8

Tengo instalado `Node 18` y he instalado el `Angular cli 8` de manera local en una carpeta, como es una versión antigua me salen ciertas advertencias de "deprecado":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego al querer crear un proyecto nuevo me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La carpeta del proyecto se llega a crear, pero me sale con errores y no se puede levantar.

Lo que quiero es poder **crear un proyecto en Angular 8**, pero no sé cómo hacerlo, pensé que con instalar el `cli v8` se podría sin problemas; no sé si es la versión del `node` la que genera el problema o que otra cosa puede ser.
**¿podrían ayudarme a poder crear un proyecto con angular 8 específicamente?**

Comment: Para empezar esa versión de nodejs no es compatible con angular 8, tienes que hacer un downgrade de node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder instalar `Angular 8` necesitas tener instaladas las siguientes versiones:

> Nodejs: 14.2.x
>
> npm: 6.14.x

Dependiendo del sistema operativo que estés usando, para el manejo de versiones de node puedes usar nvm:

### NVM - Windows

> https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

### NVM - Distros linux

> https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Puedes obtener más información sobre la instalación de Angular 8 en este link: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular8/angular8_installation.htm